# Can you internalize the single sorted definition of a category without pullbacks?

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

[nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/single-sorted+definition+of+a+category#internalization) suggests falling back to pullbacks to internalize the single sorted definition of a category. But can we internalize single sorted categories here without pullbacks?

I have an idea but I'm not quite sure it makes sense. I have a hunch it's sort of equivalent to proving pullbacks exist anyway? It's sort of like "Closed Cartesian" where you don't actually have a Cartesian product but the concept is basically equivalent to having one. I think this is sort of like using Cartesian products anyhow even if they aren't explicitly mentioned.

Source

$$ \text{s}\colon \text{Hom}(C, C) $$

Target

$$ \text{t}\colon \text{Hom}(C, C) $$

Composition

$$  - \cdot -\colon \forall A, \{ f\colon \text{Hom}(A, C), g \colon \text{Hom}(A, C) \mid \text{s} \circ f = \text{t} \circ g \} \rightarrow \text{Hom}(A , C )$$

Identity

$$ (\text{t} \circ f) \cdot f =  f$$
$$  f \cdot (\text{s} \circ f) = f$$

Associativity

$$(f \cdot g) \cdot h = f \cdot (g \cdot h)$$

Then the usual rules for the source and target of an object.

$$  \text{s} \circ \text{s} = \text{t} \circ \text{s} = \text{s} $$

$$ \text{s} \circ \text{t} = \text{t} \circ \text{t} = \text{t}$$

I have a feeling you also want some kind of naturality rule something like

$$ (f \circ h) \cdot (g \circ h) = (f \cdot g) \circ h $$

Comment: Is the domain of composition, which you wrote as "$\forall A, \{ f\colon \text{Hom}(A, C), g \colon \text{Hom}(A, C) \mid \text{s} \circ f = \text{t} \circ g \}$" supposed to be an object of your category? If so, what object is it, and how do you construct it?

Comment: @AlexKruckman no it's just a pair of Hom arrows obeying sf = tg. I started with a different approach that used Cartesian products and a mono d and definite description. $ f \in  g = \iota h. f = g \circ h$. You get stuff like $\text{comp} \circ \langle \text{comp} \circ \langle f, g \rangle \in \text{d}, h \rangle \in \text{d} = \text{comp} \circ \langle f, \text{comp} \circ \langle g , h\rangle \in \text{d} \rangle \in \text{d}$. It was kind of ugly but might be better.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. So what you're saying is that for every object $A$, the hom set $\mathrm{Hom}(A,C)$ is equipped with a partial operation $\cdot$, where $f\cdot g$ is defined whenever $s\circ f = t\circ g$. In other words, your idea is to equip every hom set with the structure of a (single-sorted) category. Yes, if you do this in such a way that $\mathrm{Hom}(-,C)$ is a functor to $\mathsf{Cat}$, this is a reasonable notion of "$C$ is an internal category".

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not really sure if this buys me anything though. It's a little like defining a category internal to the category of presheafs. It kind of makes sense but I'm not sure if it really does what I want.

Comment: Well, that's the pattern for algebraic objects internal to categories. E.g. a group internal to $C$ is the same thing as a representable functor $C^{\mathrm{op}}\to \mathsf{Grp}$, which is the same thing as a group internal to $\mathsf{Set}^{C^{\text{op}}}$ whose "underlying presheaf" is representable. See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group+object#InTermsOfPresheavesOfGroups

Comment: @AlexKruckman Huh so earlier I was thinking of "category internal to the category of presheafs with the sort a Yoneda embedding" but I thought that was too simple. But I think what you're telling me is a different more general version of that (aside from representable being up to isomorphism instead of strictly equal.)

Comment: @MolossusSpondee Yep, this is exactly the definition you're looking for: a category in the presheaf category whose object of morphisms is representable. The point is that since the Yoneda embedding preserves and reflects whatever limits exist, when pullbacks do exist the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: @KevinArlin huh so what happens if pullbacks don't exist? I was wondering because my motivation in the first place was to generalize to categories internal to closed monoidal categories and not just categories with pullbacks. Concretely I wanted to play with linear logic.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “what happens”, but none of this has any connection to a monoidal product. There is an idea of an internal category in a monoidal category described on nLab though.

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category+in+a+monoidal+category thanks I think I have much more reading to do